# Python script giving back error when attempting to load from file using JSON

Tags: python, json

I'm attempting to load two dictionaries using JSON. I save them with the following function:

```
 def save_file(self):
        print(save_dict['filename'])
        with open(save_dict['filename'], 'w') as f:
            save_list = [save_dict, cad_dict]
            json.dump(save_list, f)
```

I then attempt to load them using this function:

```
def open_file(self):
        global save_dict
        global cad_dict

        filename = fd.askopenfilename(
            initialdir=r'C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\Code\Python\Surveying_Program',
            title='Browse',
            filetype = (('job files', '*.saj'), ("all files","*.*"))
        )
        with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            save_list = json.load(f)

        save_dict = save_list[0]
        cad_dict = save_list[1]
```

I end up with the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__       
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\Tim\Desktop\Code\Python\Surveying_Program\survey_amateur_main.py", line 187, in open_file
    save_list = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 64467 (char 64466)
PS C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\Code\Python\Surveying_Program>
```

For reference, here is an example of the file I'm attempting to load:

> [{"filename": "C:/Users/Tim/Desktop/Code/Python/Surveying_Program/dxf_practice/job_file.saj", "point_dict": {"filename": "", "1": {"northing": 780443.4568, "easting": 2039690.279, "elevation": 286.5, "description": "Walls", "time": "10:25:11", "date": "11/25/2022"}}}, {"cad_filename": "C:/Users/Tim/Desktop/Code/Python/Surveying_Program/dxf_practice/one_object_dxf.dxf", "dxf_extents": [[1125.591828718476, 5050.379053781544], [1131.50998529643, 5054.804957938229]], "dxf_lines": [["0", [1125.591828718476, 5050.379053781544, 0.0], [1131.50998529643, 5054.804957938229, 0.0]]], "dxf_plines": [], "dxf_mtext": [], "dxf_circles": [], "dxf_arcs": []}]

Comment: Are you sure the file is utf-8 encoded?

Comment: Apologies, that isn't supposed to be in there and this error is from without it.

Comment: I would check character 64466 in whatever file is failing. Maybe a value that isn’t properly escaped?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't look closely at my data and my ezdxf module was putting the coordinates as a an object that evidently doesn't work well with json. Converted those objects to strings and it now works.